# vm workstation linux ip setting and putty connection

Tags: virtual-machine, ip

[image]

If you look at the picture, you'll see the Network Settings on VMWare Workstation. With this setting, I could not connect to the Linux VM with PuTTY. What have I incorrectly set?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the picture alone, it won't work from your host. I suggest setting it to Bridged mode, so that it gets an IP address on your current network. Then, you'll be able to connect to it from other computers in your network.

Comment: How do you set it to bridged mode?

Comment: You'll likely need to stop the vm. Are you following a tutorial online, or just playing around to learn?

Answer (score 0):

As the above your picture, I assure you're using NAT network...so please check your VMnet8 interface in your physical machine.

Maybe it's related to your firewall too, please try to disable and access again.